# ListDatasets() returning empty array on sde workspace

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to get list of datasets within sde connection.This sde connection is already present in ArcMap and all datasets are visible. I am posting snapshot my code. It is returning empty array,though there are clearly many datasets available. What is the problem with my code?
[image]

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Vijay\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcCatalog\xxx.sde"
featureDatasets = arcpy.ListDatasets()
print featureDatasets
for fc in featureDatasets:
    try:
        print fc
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: Add the code as text instead of a screenshot. What are you trying to list? For example ListDatasets will not list Feature Classes. Try adding an r in front of the path, `r"C:\...."`

Comment: Datasets or feature classes? What does it look like in ArcCatalog (ok to screen shot that and paste into your question). How are you running this? From catalog, IDLE, CMD, ArcMap? Is your username and password saved in that connection file?

Comment: I want list of feature datasets only.Feature classes are within datasets.And adding r at front of path, r"C:\..." is still giving empty array.

Comment: Works just fine for me, either your credentials aren't stored in your connection file or the connecting user lacks permissions to view the datasets.. of course it could be that you're executing from the IDLE shell which is known to be a bit flaky, try it from the python window of ArcCatalog or ArcMap and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah it works in python window of ArcMap. Thanks for the suggestion.But why it might not be working in IDLE?Also there is no issue of permissions.Beacuse this connection file is working for another script.

Comment: I don't know why IDLE is a problem, just that it can be annoying. I personally use PyWin32 which is open source and has good intelisense (saves a lot of spelling mistakes) after importing the modules in the interactive window.. Notepad++ is also ok but lacks the intelisense and interactive window.

Comment: Your exception handling is decidedly strange, since `print` isn't likely to throw an exception there. In this context, "Dataset" is a *Feature Dataset" (the folder object in which Feature Classes can be organized). Without raw formatting, the workspace is invalid.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Okay I will look into PyWin32 .Thanks

Comment: @Vince On third line "print featureDatasets" it should return array of feature datasets. But its empty.And for formatting of path, I tried double slashes and r"C:\" also.

Comment: It ***does*** print the array of datasets. That array is empty. You should focus on whether `os.path.exists(arcpy.env.workspace)` returns `True`.

Comment: @Vince os.path.exists(arcpy.env.workspace) is returning true.

Comment: This is the point where the requested screenshot from the Catalog tool with the opened connection would be useful. This looking more like a Support issue. It's not clear which exact version of ArcGIS is in use and if 64-bit geoprocessing is installed (please [Edit] the question to include the raw modifier and include all the information provided in this lengthy comment log).