# ArcGIS Pro 2.7 ArcPy ListDatasets() and ListFeatureClasses() returning empty on SDE workspace

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

(I know there was a similar question also unanswered [ListDatasets() returning empty array on sde workspace](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316966/listdatasets-returning-empty-array-on-sde-workspace), but I couldn't comment on it. Sorry for the duplicate.)

I am trying to run a script to export a feature class (that is in a feature dataset) from my organization's main SDE to a scratch geodatabase, then do further analysis. The FeatureClassToFeatureClass function repeatedly failed. I verified that it was spelled correctly, and decided to try listing datasets and feature classes to see how it looked and properly format the string to capture the feature class. This script was initially written for ArcPy on ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1, ran well there, and is being rewritten for ArcPy on ArcGIS Pro 2.7.

RDBMS: Oracle Enterprise, geodatabase version is 10.3.1, and ArcGIS Pro 2.7 says it's compatible.

Here's my code:

```
#Set workspace 1 - My version SDE
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Esri/ArcGISPro/Favorites/MAIN USERNAME.sde"
print("Workspace set.")

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
ds = arcpy.ListDatasets()
```

Username and password are stored in the SDE file, and it has many feature classes and datasets. However, when the script above runs, both `fcs` and `ds` return empty.

Comment: Does the SDE connection file work in Pro GUI if you try to open it at the location given?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the RDBMS in use, the version of that release, the version of any installed client libraries, and the version of the geodatatbae itself. 10.4.1 is as old as it supported by Esri now; if the database is older than that, it can't be supported by modern EGDB libraries.

Comment: @vince, even the sun set on 10.4.1 this past February 1: ([Esri Support ArcMap 10.4. (10.4.1)](https://support.esri.com/en/Products/Desktop/arcgis-desktop/arcmap/10-4-1#product-support)

Comment: When mentioning an earlier Q&A from this site please always include a link to it in your question body.

Comment: @Vince information added. Other Python scripts have been able to talk to this SDE through this same connection file.

Comment: @bixb0012 Yes, the same connection file is used in my Pro Favorites to access our org's primary central GDB.

Comment: A 10.3.1 geodatabase?  Time for an upgrade.  Have you tried not relying on defaults and explicitly passing arguments, e.g., `fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")`

Comment: @bixb0012 agreed, but it's not actually my call for long, complicated, organization reasons. I'm not the admin. Adding the "*" argument fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "*" to List Feature Datasets, [as suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425909/arcgis-pro-2-7-arcpy-listdatasets-and-listfeatureclasses-returning-empty-on/426072#comment695229_425909), fixed the issue.